# Многостраничник на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть несколько страничек написанных на html: index, first, second.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке я мог прописать, например, <название сайта>/first и мне отобразилась страница first.html?

Если это важно, то с фронтендом давно занимаюсь, а с бэкендом только-только начинаю знакомство

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь о простых HTML страницах, то просто положить их в папки с соответствующими именами:

```
/first/index.html
/second/index.html
```

Если речь о Wordpress, то нужно в настройках (Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки) указать "Название записи" и просто создать необходимые страницы, задав им соответствующий slug.

Если у этих страниц разная верстка, то также нужно создать отдельные шаблоны страниц.

Comment: "нужно создать отдельные шаблоны страниц" - вот этот совет решил мой вопрос. Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю верстка для всех страниц разная. Значит вариантов несколько:

1. Вы создаете страницы в теме создаете page-{slug}.php (где slug - это
   слаг записи)
2. Вы создаете несколько шаблонов и назначить их в админке: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Как вы поняли про разность вёрстки? Этого из вопроса не следует.

Comment: Дедукция :) Верстальщик никогда не будет создавать лишние html файлы, чтобы менять только контент

Comment: А кто сказал, что он верстальщик? Сейчас каждая домохозяйка может за пару дней освоить html и сделать свой "типа сайт".

Comment: в вопросе указано, что давно он фронтом занимается)